# My program won't load an image off a website (C#)

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

Today while using a program I wrote a couple years ago, I have run into a situation where loading a thumbnail off of a website ends up timing out instead of loading. My Web Browser is able to open the file just fine and after a few hours of troubleshooting, I am out of ideas.

```
public static Image GetThumbNail(OnlineImageInfo info)
    {
        //Check if thumbnail has been cached to disk
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}{1}", Config.ActiveConfig.ThumbnailCachePath.FullName,
            info.PreveiwFileName));
        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            //Generate a web request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(info.PreveiwURL);
            request.Method = "GET";

            request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
            request.Timeout = 10000; //I added the timeout to stop the program from hanging while trying to load this thumbnail
            WebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
                //cache the image to disk
                using (var fs = file.Create())
                {
                    using (var strm = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        strm.CopyTo(fs);
                        fs.Flush();
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                //timed out
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                    response.Dispose();
            }


        }
        //Load image from disk to RAM
        Image result = null;
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        using (var fs = TryGetFileStream(file))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(mem);
            result = Image.FromStream(mem);
        }


        return result;
    }
```

The strange part is of the thousands of thumbnails I've loaded off of this website, I have never had this happen before. Can anyone think of why this file would time out on my program and not my browser or how I can go about troubleshooting it further?

Edit:
After trying the suggestions in the comments below to no avail, I tried forcing the request as Http instead of Https, and low and behold it suddenly works. I'd like to figure out why I'm getting this behavior, but at least its working now.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(info.PreveiwURL.Replace("https:","http:"));
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Referer = info.SourceWebsite;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0";
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            WebResponse response = null;
```

Comment: I would open the web browser network monitor and check for redirections that could potentially alter the behaviour spected or especify a real browser user agent, maybe IE.

Comment: Its doubtful you could get help if code seems fine and you provide no [mcve]

Comment: Some basic debugging would probably solve your problem. Open the pgoram, set a breakpoint at the start of the method and go through it step-by-step. I suspect it goes to first block on `if (!file.Exists)`, because if it worked before and nothing changed in the program, that only leaves the website and target data...

Comment: @bradbury9 I have tried using an IE and Fire Fox user agent and its still not working. I am not seeing any redirects on the network monitor either.

Comment: @Zero this is how I found the error in the first place (given, i had to go through about 1,000 lines to get to this function)
the program hangs on `response = request.GetResponse();` when the program tried to load a specific thumbnail off of a website, while hundreds of others load just fine. I'm suspecting an issue with the website's config, but why only a single file?

Comment: There are sometimes websites with controls to prevent web scraping, to ensure that the content is server to actual humans instead of programs/bots. A usual way is checking that the referral matched its website

Comment: @bradbury9 Just tried setting `request.Referer` to the website, and to the search results page, it still ends up timing out.